# Construct a javascript date from a string without timezone (for JqueryUI datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, timezone

I'm using the jQueryUI Datepicker library and I need to supply it with a date that is dynamically loaded for the min date.

I set up my datepicker:

```
$("#thePicker" ).datepicker({
             dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
             showOtherMonths: true,
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             minDate: new Date('2016-04-28'),
        });
```

Where '2016-04-28' is a string that could vary when loaded.

This though sets the minimum allowable date to April 27, 2016, due to a timezone conversion.

How should I construct this new Date for the minDate when I have a string of the format shown above supplied so that no timezone is relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is a string and always "YYYY-MM-DD", I would do something like this:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Twisty/eknxxqvh/

```
$(function() {
  var dString = "2016-04-28";
  var yy = parseInt(dString.substring(0, 4));
  var mm = parseInt(dString.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
  var dd = parseInt(dString.substring(8));
  $("#thePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: makeDate("2016-04-28"),
    /* Alternate Method 1
    minDate: new Date(yy, mm, dd),
    /* Alternate Method 2
    minDate: new Date(parseInt("2016-04-28".substring(0,4)), parseInt("2016-04-28".substring(5,7))-1, parseInt("2016-04-28".substring(8))),
    */
  });

  function makeDate(ds) {
    var yy = parseInt(ds.substring(0, 4));
    var mm = parseInt(ds.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
    var dd = parseInt(ds.substring(8));
    var d = new Date(yy, mm, dd);
    return d;
  }
});
```

Depending on how often you will be using this in your page will define what method will work best for you.

Comment: Ah great, thank you. Used the makeDate function in my common javascript as this is done around the app. I guess the Date constructor that takes a string will infer the timezone.

Comment: Yes, it will assume the users local timezone and when you pass that little info, it may make some strange assumptions.